# Starter kit for Muay Thai

Tags: muay-thai, self-training

My plan is to buy a heavy bag , a stand and gloves . Should the bag be 100 lbs or 150 lbs? (my weight is 149 lbs) What kind of gloves should I buy ? Is there anything else important that I should know about the equipment?

Is there any stand that doesn't affect so much the footwork? Could a free standing bag work better than a bag placed on a stand? What are the drawbacks of a free standing bag?

Comment: Do you have any access to coaching/proper training? If not, then you're more likely to hurt yourself than anyone else.

Comment: I think that I have the perception to train  myself safely . Why should I hurt someone else? Is that what learn in the proper training?

Comment: If you haven't had proper training then no, you cannot train safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to self-train then I would suggest that you start with a softer bag. A hard bag may lead to you hurting your hands or wrists whilst punching. I would go for a hanging bag and gloves. Try 16 oz gloves as these are nice and padded.

The drawbacks of a free-hanging bag are that it will move when you hit it and it can burst/ fall off its fastening through hard use.

When you learn (I am guessing off YouTube?) look at the right way to make a fist and also the right foot shape for kicks. These are the first things that a good instructor will teach you so you do not hurt yourself.

But I would say... take a few lessons :)

Comment: I was doing karate when I was a child. I had 4 belts. Then my parents didnt let me continue it.  Now I am kicking an old office chair and i dont have the bag yet. After 1 and a half hour of kicking (axe and roundhouse) I was really tired, the next day my adductor muscles were sore. I guess I need more focus on fitness and stretching and i am working on it.

Comment: no one gave an answer for 3 days. I have ordered a stand for the bag, a 100 lbs bag (banana ), wraps for the hands ...  thanks for the tips tho

Comment: Your welcome. Enjoy the training. Always good to do dynamic stretching before and at the end of training.  I think the chair will be happy when your bag arrives...

Answer (score -1):

When you get the 16 oz gloves as @NeilNeil's answer suggests make sure you get some hand wraps. They're not so important if you're punching pads that someone is holding, but you'll end up damaging your wrists and hands if you use a heavy bag.

There are tons of videos on youtube to demonstrate how to wrap your hands, find something that works for you. The main thing to look for is that the fist you make should be tighter after you've wrapped it.

Comment: Would badly wrapping one's hands cause damage? Yes,  it would...  Without a teacher,  this is dangerous advise.

Comment: @Sardathrion yes but hand wrapping is one of the few things in martial arts you CAN learn on youtube :)